# Explicit casting in variable definitions

Tags: c++, casting

Is the explicit casting portion "static_cast()" redundant in a situation like the following?

```
int m = 5;
double r = static_cast<double>(m);
```

Comment: Casts like this are often written explicitly to silence compiler warnings. It says "I am sure that this cast is correct, don't warn me about issues with it". For example `double` might not be able to represent all `int` values exactly, which a compiler might warn about.

Comment: @user17732522 — it says “this **conversion** is correct”.

Answer (score 0):

Yes; c++ will implicitly convertan int to a double, so there’s no need to make an explicit cast.

Comment: The `double` may not be able to represent the `int` exactly though. The cast may be needed to silence compiler warnings about that.

Comment: The compiler will implicitly **convert** the int to double. A cast is always explicit; it’s something you write in your source code to tell the compiler to do a conversion.